# Is possible to configure a SFTP session including a command to copy a file to the remote device with MobaXterm?

Tags: mobaxterm

Is possible to configure a SFTP session including a command to copy a file to the remote device with MobaXterm?

I should need to automatically connect and copy a file in `/tmp/` folder.